# GitHub Actions - Running DotNetCore Tests with Neo4j service dependency

Tags: docker, neo4j, github-actions

I would need some help with steps to run integration tests on GitHub. My project needs Neo4j so I have declared `neo4j` as a service. However while running my test project, I am seeing the following error

```
Connection with the server breaks due to ExtendedSocketException: 
Resource temporarily unavailable Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct 
host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. 
Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0.
```

I am not sure if the issue is with how I am specifying the actions or something to do with Neo4j.

Here's my GitHub CI File: `dotnetcore.yml`

```
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, GithubActions ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      NEO4J_HOST: neo4j

    # Service containers to run with `container-job`
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      neo4j:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: neo4j:4.0.1
        ports:                    
        - 7474:7474 # used for http
        - 7687:7687 # used for bolt
        env:       
          NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/password  
          NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address: "NEO4J_HOST:7687"
          NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: "NEO4J_HOST:7687"

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore  ./src/BbcCorp.Neo4j.NeoGraphManager.sln

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore ./src/BbcCorp.Neo4j.NeoGraphManager.sln

    - name: Run Integration Tests 
      env:
        NEO4J_SERVER: NEO4J_HOST
      run: |
        cd ./src/BbcCorp.Neo4j.Tests
        docker ps
        dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal BbcCorp.Neo4j.Tests.csproj
```

I am trying to connect to: `bolt://NEO4J_HOST:7687` but it just doesn't connect.

Error Details:

```
Using Neo4j Server NEO4J_HOST:7687 as neo4j/password
Error executing query. Connection with the server breaks due to ExtendedSocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.83]     NeoGraphManagerIntegrationTests.SimpleNodeTests [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.83]       Neo4j.Driver.ServiceUnavailableException : Connection with the server breaks due to ExtendedSocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.83]       ---- System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException : Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The settings file for my C# test project looks like this

```
{
    "NEO4J_SERVER": "localhost",
    "NEO4J_PORT": 7687,
    "NEO4J_DB_USER": "neo4j",
    "NEO4J_DB_PWD": "password"
}
```

The tests runs fine from my local machine but fails when we execute on GitHub.

Comment: - 7474:7474 # used for http.
NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address: "NEO4J_HOST:7687", shouldnt these match?

Answer (score 1):

Today I was setting up my github action for my open source project and after searching everywhere I found a solution that worked well for me.

For me it was with this code where when creating the service I configure it to do the test, which is what I need it for. I hope it can be of help to you.

```
name: SonarCloud
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

env:  
  NEO4J_USER: neo4j
  NEO4J_PASSWORD: neo4jSocial
  JAVA_VERSION: 21
    
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and analyze
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      neo4j:
        image: neo4j:5.15.0-enterprise
        env:
          NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: apoc.*
          NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_enabled: "true"
          NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled: "true"
          NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled: "true"
          NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config: "true"
          NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT: "yes"
          NEO4J_dbms_security_auth__enabled: "false"
          NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: localhost:7687
          NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS: '["apoc"]'
          NEO4J_AUTH: ${{ env.NEO4J_USER }}/${{ env.NEO4J_PASSWORD }}
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "cypher-shell 'match (n) return count(n)'"
          --health-timeout 10s
          --health-retries 20
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-start-period 30s
        ports:
          - 7687:7687
                
    steps:
```

In case you still have problems, I invite you to see this publication, which is another way to do it but with auraDB
https://neo4j.com/developer-blog/neo4j-integration-tests-github-actions-aura-cli/